# browser tries to use the ssl certficate of website A for non ssl of website B on nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, redirect, html-lists

I have two websites running on the same server.

keurigkeuren.nl and noxxie.nl.

keurigkeuren.nl is on a SSL certficate, noxxie.nl is not.

When I check the records of noxxie.nl:
https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/?q=noxxie.nl

The server tries to server the SSL certicate of keurigkeuren.nl, I am pulling my hair out here, cause lets encrypt cannot serve a SSL certifcate for it cause it just tries to use the ssl certficate of the other website.

Does anyone know where I can start looking for the problem?

keurigkeuren.nl redirect

```
server {
    listen: 80;
    listen [::]: 80;

    server_name .keurigkeuren.nl;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

and for noxxie.nl

```
server {
    listen: 80;
    listen [::]: 80;

    server_name www.noxxie.nl;
    return 301 $scheme://noxxie.nl$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: From what you show (don't mention missen semicolons after `server_name` directive). The first server block doing redirect from http to https for `keurigkeuren.nl` domain and any of its subdomains. The second sever block doing redirect from `http://www.keurigkeuren.nl` to `http://noxxie.nl`.

Comment: I updated my question it was a typo :(

Comment: The only server block listening on 443 port is for `keurigkeuren.nl`? Then it would be used by nginx for any incoming SSL connection on this IP address because no other blocks that can serve a SSL requests are defined. Still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: well the problem here is, that lets encrypt does not get the noxxie.nl domain it just redirect to keurigkeuren.nl causing the acme challenge to fail :(.

Comment: Sounds weird. ACME challenge of HTTP-01 type uses the plain HTTP protocol on port 80, at least letsencrypt documentation [states](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/) so (and I never heard about any problems related to this).